# Installing KMS on a DC... good idea or bad?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, kms

What are your thoughts on installing a KMS server on a DC?  Any drawbacks?

Comment: Another question... does it work on core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly this. As Hyppy said, it's a very low impact application as all it is doing is passing data through. Do be careful of KMS versions, though as there is some variation. I ended up running one on 2003 and another on 2008R2 because of what they each were able to license.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what KMS can license on each platform?  Does the latest version not license *everything*?

Comment: Microsoft got confusing with it. Office 2007 and 2010 use slightly different KMS as I recall. I'd have to look it up, but I think 2008R2 does it all.

Comment: @maker - 2008R2 does it all.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a big deal. Licensing is such a tiny application, and the attack surface is a single port on a service I've never seen a vulnerability for (though you may want to double-check on that). If you can, go ahead and make sure it's 2008 R2 so that Office 2010 KMS/volume licensing is supported.